# Discrepancy with structure.sql in Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, postgresql-12, dbmigrate

We have a Rails 4 app right now that is using Postgresql. All the devs today got upgraded/downgraded to the same version: PostgreSQL 12.6.

However, for a couple of us, when we run `rake db:migrate` the alterations to `structure.sql` seem to be slightly different, and I can't figure out why.

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I see this for one of the sequences:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.payroll_fields_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

Whereas when one of my co-workers runs `rake db:migrate` they see this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.payroll_fields_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

without the `AS integer` line

It's bugging us that we can't figure out why there is a discrepancy since we are both on the same version of Postgres, the same version of Rails and the same version of Ruby.

Any thoughts? Does anyone know where/how Rails decides on what goes in `structure.sql`?

Thanks!

Comment: Rails 4 is just a historical artifact at this point, so it's entirely possible this is some kind of flaw that was fixed in later versions. For what it's worth, I believe the SQL schema dump mode just uses `pg_dump` or equivalent, so you may have slightly different settings in play. It's worth comparing to the SQL output of that to see if this is a Postgres problem, not a Rails one.

Comment: `structure:dump` just shells out to [`pg_dump --schema-only`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/291a3d2ef29a3842d1156ada7526f4ee60dd2b59/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L49).